# How to find the versions of spring projects in a Spring Boot version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have been looking to find out which versions of the various spring projects are included in a specific version of spring boot.

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong spot but it seems difficult to locate for example which version of spring data that spring boot 1.4.0 might be using.

The reason why is that there was a specific version of the spring data couchbase that I wanted because of a feature and I can't determine whether it is available apriori.

Is there a place where this is written up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind.  Found it.  For example, here it is: https://web.archive.org/web/20180815100113/https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: @SpringLearner I replaced the broken link

Comment: Or go straight to the docs release archives at Spring which go way back too:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/ Dependencies and such are found under the appendixes of the docs.